# infowindow Android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en android que tiene un mapa en el cual al dar clic en un marker muestra el infowindow de la siguiente manera:

mi duda es como agrego una imagen diferentes a cada marker y si es posible como llamo las imágenes de un servidor como cloudinary para no almacenar todo en la app, soy nuevo en android. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para esto tienes que crear un `InfoWindowAdapter` personalizado, que contenga la referencia al `ImageView` y cargar las imágenes desde los recursos,  este es un ejemplo:

```
    public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

        private static final String TAG = "CustomInfoWindowAdapter";
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater){
            this.inflater = inflater;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(final Marker m) {
            //Carga layout personalizado.
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);       

             Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mi_imagen);                                                            
            //Carga imagen.   
            ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_image)).setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
               ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_city)).setText("Sidney");
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_lat)).setText("-10.79");
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_lon)).setText("-77.71");      
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker m) {
                return null;
            }        
        }
```

Para cargar el infoWindow personalizado, a tu GoogleMap lo realizas mediante el método [`setInfoWindowAdapter()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) donde tu le asignas el  [`InfoWindowAdapter`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) personalizado.

```
myGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())));
```

Comment: esta linea de código va en el mapsactivity

myGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())));

lo siento aun soy nuevo en esto ya cree mi infowindow res>layout>infowindow_layout.xml

Comment: myGoogleMap es la instancia de tu google map. y si va dentro de tu MapActivity.